# IE issues with PayPal In-Context Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm implementing PayPal's In-Context flow for Express Checkout as specified in the documentation. Everything works as expected in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. IE, however, gives me some issues.

When I click the "Checkout with PayPal" image, the page goes dark and the modal window opens above it to PayPal's login/signup page as it should. But just before the page loads in the modal window, the page behind it turns white again, allowing users to interact with it which it shouldn't. I'm still able to go through with logging in and things in the modal window, yet the page behind it is active.

The second issue deals with redirecting. In IE, the modal window NEVER disappears after clicking the "Continue" button, which redirects to a specified url on my server. The redirect happens alright; it just doesn't happen in the main window as it should but instead happens in the modal window. Simply put, everything that occurs after pressing the "Continue" button happens in the modal window with no more interaction with the main window.

Again, everything works in other browsers (I've yet to test things in Safari), but IE (v.11) isn't behaving correctly. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce issue in my implementation (IE). Any (blocking) script errors  specific to IE?

Comment: @EdSF None that I could find. Anyway, I tried adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> inside the head element of my webpage like the PayPal docs say. That didn't work either. I'll keep testing and will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Do you have it up somewhere (like a test site)?

Comment: @EdSF Unfortunately, no. It's a test site on my home machine built with VS 2013 Community and ASP.NET web pages.

Comment: I discovered that this problem happens to me when I add an onError callback, and it goes away when I remove the onError callback. IE seems is the only browser that the onError callback causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar issue with IE/Firefox when I was using custom button images.
To overcome I just had to remove the button variable  and let the javasript generate its own button.

```
window.paypalCheckoutReady = function() {
            paypal.checkout.setup('S4X5XW328WAYY', {
                container: 'myContainer', 
                environment: 'sandbox'
                // button: 'incontext_id'//commented

            });
```

Demo and PHP sample code [here](http://www.techycommerce.com/uncategorized/express-checkout-in-context-integration-in-php/)

Comment: I'm not using the button parameter either and the problem still persists only in IE (v.11), yet your demo works as expected. The only differences between your code and my code (after viewing the source of your demo page) is that I set the container parameter to a link rather than a form. Also, checkout.js is retrieved from PayPal in my code instead of being loaded from my server. I'll make some changes and let you know if they worked or not.

Comment: Changing my code to reflect the example given above had no effect. IE 11 is still not working. As a quick fix, I think I'll set IE to go through the normal flow while other browsers get the In-Context flow.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @Dude-Dastic at the point when I wrote this I was still struggling with the basics, but in the end (after a lot more struggling) I almost had the opposite problem. The generated buttons (which completely make no sense with my UI) were being generated but only the FIRST one would even work at all. I really wanted custom buttons that I could make any size. I never ended up with the actual OP's issue with weird overlays. I ended up successfully using `button: ['payPal1', 'payPal2']` on my site which hooks up the events and finally after an infuriating day I managed to get it all working.

Comment: Still thinking about making a video tutorial where I swear the whole way through - the PayPal in-context API and docs are appauling and you have to be a detective not a programmer to figure it all out. Will report back if sales are low for any particular browser having switched to in-context

Comment: note you can replace the merchant ID with a single space to make the code more generic and to keep your merchant ID off the internet